# Predicates grouping in JSONpath using Jayway Implementation

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am trying to use JSONpath to query my JSON Object. The logical || or && operator is working. But, when I try to group my predicates then perform the logical || or && operations it seems not to be working.  [Source](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#inline-predicates)

E.g.

```
$..[?(@.book=='fiction' && @.store=='online')]
```

E.g.

```
$..[?(@.store=='online' || @.store=='offline') && (@.NER=='observation')]
```

The second one doesn't work. Any pointers as to where the error is or is that functionality not yet supported

Answer (score 2):

? should be covering all the conditions. i.e., overall rounded bracket missing.

Correct path:

```
$..[?((@.store=='online' || @.store=='offline') && (@.NER=='observation'))]
```

I have verified it with different example at http://jsonpath.com/

Sample JSON:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Path with multiple conditions:

```
$..[?((@.category=='fiction' || @.author=='Nigel Rees') && (@.price < 10))]
```

Result:

```
'0' ...
  'category' => "fiction"
  'author' => "Nigel Rees"
  'title' => "Sayings of the Century"
  'price' => "8.95"
'1' ...
  'category' => "fiction"
  'author' => "Herman Melville"
  'title' => "Moby Dick"
  'isbn' => "0-553-21311-3"
  'price' => "8.99"
```